# Editing component link component in XPM with DXA 2.1

Tags: dxa, experience-manager, dxa-2.1

In my DXA 2.1 based stage website, I wanted to make my component links editable. I have a main component that has some Embeddable fields and some component link fields. Using Html helper extension methods I decorated html with DXAEntityMarkup and DXAPropertyMarkup. It works fine for text based fields and other embeddable fields. However in case of component links, it does not work. Can you please guide me how to make component links editable in XPM in DXA 2.1?

Thanks.